# Js get Objects from Array Objects, by property in nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, array-filter

How filter this array by property in nested array `tagList === 'new'` in nested objects.

```
const myArray=[
  { 
    "name": "myItem",
    "tagList": ["hot", "new"]
  },
  { 
    "name": 'myItem2'
    "tagList": ["new"]
  },
  { 
    "name": "myItem3"
    "tagList": []
  },
]
```

I want get new array with `Objects.tagList === new`.

```
  { 
    "name": "myItem",
    "tagList": ["hot", "new"]
  },
  { 
    "name": 'myItem2'
    "tagList": ["new"]
  },
```

trying this

```
const newArray = myArray.filter((item) => item.tagList === 'new')
```

or

```
const newArray = myArray.filter(i => i.tagList.includes('new'))
```

get empty Array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: check the syntax of the array, second solution will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have copy pasted the code but the input array definition misses a few commas resulting syntax errors. Fixing that your code works as expected. I.e.

```js
const myArray=[
  { 
    "name": "myItem",
    "tagList": ["hot", "new"]
  },
  { 
    "name": 'myItem2',
    "tagList": ["new"]
  },
  { 
    "name": "myItem3",
    "tagList": []
  },
]

const newArray = myArray.filter(i => i.tagList.includes('new'))

console.log(newArray)
```

logs an array with two items to the console. See fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/oxra0j9w/